# running shell command in php with realtime output

Tags: php, shell

I am uploading a file via php  `move_uploaded_file` function and then the file is then taken as a parameter of a java program. while the java program is executing, it outputs the progress in the terminal. The output of the java program is input of a perl script which does the same. 
I am executing all of them in my php web site as shell_exec functions and printing them on screen

```
    echo "Running java ..... ";
    $output=shell_exec("java -jar abc.jar ".( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']));
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    echo "running perl .....";
    $output=shell_exec("perl abc.pl outputfromjava.txt");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

The shell commands are running fine but the output from java and perl isn't displayed on my web site. I tried refreshing the page in my code after java and perl is executed but it then refreshes the upload too.

The output is now

```
Running java ....
Running Perl ....
```

How should I write my php so that the output is

```
Running Java...
Progress1 //from java output
progress2 //from java output
Running Perl....
Progress1 //from perl output
progress2 //from perl output
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable output buffering using `ob_end_flush`, and start the process using `proc_open` instead of `shell_exec`, so you have full control over the file descriptors and don't need to wait for the process to finish to get the output. When you have started the process using `proc_open`, read from its STDOUT and STDERR and output it to the browser, possibly with a `flush` to assure your output is not kept in any buffer.

Comment: I used system instead of shell_exec and it worked. Does proc_open have any extra advantage over system?

Comment: definitely! you basically get full control over the process and its fd's (input/output). That is, your script keeps continues (after `proc_open`) while the command is running, giving a lot of potential benefits.

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution: (tested on Windows machine + wamp server)

```php
header('Content-Encoding: none;');

set_time_limit(0);

if (ob_get_level() == 0) {
    ob_start();
}

$handle = popen("<<< Your Shell Command >>>", "r");

while(!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = trim(htmlspecialchars(fgets($handle)));
    echo $buffer . "<br />" . str_pad('', 4096);    
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
pclose($handle);
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: i have tried ur code,,actually its not displaying shell command in real time, but just wait shell command to finish load all text and displaying it bit by bit using sleep(1) help.
sorry, u deserve downvote

Answer (score -1):

try `> file.txt` then the read file.

:)